# Constraints working on iPhone 8 but not on iPhone 8 Plus

Tags: ios, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint, xcode10

I have applied constraints which work on all the iPhone __, iPhone XS Max devices but on iPhone __ Plus devices, the same don't work. What could be a possible solution for this?

I checked the dimensions in viewDidLoad and viewDidAppear. The constraints are maintained in viewDidLoad but break in viewDidAppear in case of Plus devices. I have pinned the UIView to the safe area (left, top, right) and given it a height of 40.

In view did load, screen width is 414 and the view's width is 414
In view did appear, the screen is 414 and uiview is 453.

I am not facing this issue on non Plus devices.

expected:

[image]

getting:

[image]

Comment: Not enough information.

Comment: edited! Is there any other information I should provide?

Comment: @Anika Please, Share Current and expected Output Screenshots.

Comment: @NikunjKumbhani added current and expected wireframe screenshots

Comment: @Anika how to make a layout for the top three subviews?

Comment: @NikunjKumbhani I have given the rightmost subview a distance of 12 from the safe area, using the auto layout. The issue is that the entire view crosses the bounds of the screen. The main uiview containing all the subviews

Comment: @Anika from where you add constraints on views

Comment: from Xcode or form code

Comment: @Anika You Used Scrollview or not?

Comment: @BijenderSinghShekhawat I added from the storyboard

Comment: @NikunjKumbhani I have not used a scrollview as I did not need one.

Comment: @Anika if possible share your storyboard screenshot with given constrains

Comment: @Anika I think your constraint are not work on both 8 and 8+ because you make your screens on 8 screen and when you check your screen on 6,7,8 then they work fine and when you check your screen on 6+,7+,8+ then there are some issues come. am I right?

Comment: @Bijender Singh Shekhawat he is right this is the case.

Comment: in the storyboard I confirmed all the constraints on the 8+ interface as well, they were all present. 
The constraints are followed until view did load as well.
It's in the view did appear that I see the violation. @BijenderSinghShekhawat